# Laravel Passport Expiracion del token

Tags: laravel, vue.js, passport

Tengo una app en Vue que se conecta a Laravel mediante una API para acceder a las rutas, todo está funcionando bien pero ahora veo la necesidad de establecer un tiempo de expiración de 5 minutos, que se actualize con cada llamada a la API (Esto para que expire por el tiempo de inactividad)

Establecí la expiración en mi AuthServiceProvider

```
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(5));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(5));
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(5));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(5));
```

Lo cual funciona bien, la sesión expira en 5 minutos, Ahora e buscado la forma de renovarla sin necesidad de pedirle al usuario que la renueve (Con cada petición a las rutas) cree un middleware
El cual actualiza el "expire_at" pero en la documentación dice que se debe usar solo como lectura por seguridad...
Por otro lado, le pido al usuario en siempre en el frontend cada 1 minuto antes de expirar la sesión, para mantenerla o salir de la APP.
Pero sigo encontrándome sin saber cómo actualizar el tiempo.